# AS3 to Java (boolean ? int:int)

Tags: java, actionscript-3

```
var max:int = (splitH ? height : width) - MIN_LEAF_SIZE;
```

What would this look like in java? I don't know what the as3 code is doing exactly...
Mainly the (`splitH ? height : width`) is tripping me up.

Answer (score 2):

That's a conditional operator.

Java has the exact same operator.

Answer (score 0):

It is as SLaks says.
If you would translate conditional operator line to `if` and `else` it would look something like this:

```
var max:int = 0;
if(splitH)
{
    max = height - MIN_LEAF_SIZE;
}
else
{
    max = width - MIN_LEAF_SIZE;
}
```